# How to keep Shell Script from auto-exiting?

Tags: shell, unix

I want to make a simple script, and I want to make sure that it doesn't exit until the user tells it to.

Thing is, the script isn't infinite, it is a short script that should be continuous. How can I do this?

Thanks for you help !

P.S: Unix Shell

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: @yaccz I currently have a check, and an else with a while loop. The while has a check for something else and I am _hoping_ that this will work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Please show the code you have with a `while` loop and an `else`, etc.  It sounds like you need an infinite loop around the body of the script: `while true; do ...original script...; done`. An exit from in the body of the original script will exit the program, outer loop and all.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is just to wait for user input prior to termination, `bash` and `ksh` both offer a `read` function that could be used to wait for user input:

```
echo -n "Press ENTER..."
read
```

If however the issue is to *keep running* the script until some external indication of exit, wrap it into a `while` loop and check for a flag file which would indicate the script has to exit:

```
while true; do
    ... stuff you want to run repeatedly (also think about throttling)

    if [[ -f /MY/FLAG/FILE ]]; then
        rm -f /MY/FLAG/FILE
        break
    fi
done
```